# How to disallow the execution of PHP files in a specific directory?

Tags: php, iis

I noticed huge bug on a server which allows to upload any file (including *.php) and then execute it! It's terrible! I don't know whether I should prevent uploading *.php files or disable their execution in php.ini (which I don't know how to do)

Comment: You cold use something like `$path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` to get the file extension in your upload script and then stop the upload once you detect a php file. (Or better yet, only allow it to continue if the file is of the type that you want)

Comment: Clarified title

Answer (score 0):

You can put your uploaded files outside the web root.

Also, you can set IIS to deny uploading PHP files: [IIS 8.5 deny PHP upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41714059/iis-8-5-deny-php-upload)

Also, you can set the upload folder's permission to disallow executing files inside it.

Also, you can check the files which are being uploaded for their type: http://php.net/manual/ro/function.mime-content-type.php

You can also set the permission to read/write, but not to execute.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using apache, create a .htaccess file in the folder and write the below code

```
<Files *.php>
deny from all
</Files>
```

Then save the file. This can prevent execution of PHP files in the folder

Comment: They are not using Apache. The question is tagged [tag:iis].

Answer (score -2):

If you uses Apache server, try to place into target directory file .htaccess containing string `php_flag engine  off`. This will block execution of any file as php script for this directory and all subdirectories. Also prevent uploading any file with filename starting with "."

Comment: They are not using Apache. The question is tagged [tag:iis].